# There is no sicentific mode in my pycharm

Tags: pycharm

i am following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46RjXawJQgg).it first start by introducing the ***scientific mode*** of the IDE.
I am using this version of pycharm:

[image]

Sadly, i cannot find such feature on my `Pycharm`. So ,how may i activate it?

[image: m]

Comment: Please check this link maybe it will help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have the Community version of PyCharm. The Scientific mode is sadly only supported in the Professional version.

> This feature is only supported in the Professional edition. This edition is commercial, and it provides an outstanding set of features: see the comparison matrix for more details. [Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html)

If you want to use the features of the mode, you'll have to upgrade to the correct PyCharm version.